# Early 2015 MacBook Pro running 10.13.3 kernel panics frequently

Tags: high-sierra, crash, kernel-panic

My early 2015 MBP keeps having kernel panics. I cannot seem to figure out what causes them from the error reports nor can I pin down a certain behavior that triggers them.  Has anyone also experienced similar frequent panics? I have run the built in hardware diagnostics serval times as well as EtreCheck and nothing seems to be faulty...

Specs are:

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)
- Processor 2.9 GHz Intel
- Core i5 Memory 8GB 1867 MHz DDR3
- Graphics Intel Iris Graphics 6100
  1536 MB

  Anonymous UUID:       C1236BAD-D106-F37E-7163-1D56C62AB201

  ```
  Fri Jan 26 16:56:53 2018

  *** Panic Report ***
  panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801036e339): Kernel trap at 0xffffff8010200a1c, type 14=page fault, registers:
  CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0xffffff805050600c, CR3: 0x00000001f40820fa, CR4: 0x00000000003627e0
  RAX: 0x0000000125c13000, RBX: 0x000000008febeba0, RCX: 0xffffff802e2ceed0, RDX: 0x0000000058469e02
  RSP: 0xfffffd000004c720, RBP: 0xffffff9143c13b30, RSI: 0x0000000000000008, RDI: 0xffffff8010a0af68
  R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0x0000000000000016, R10: 0xffffff8010a0c118, R11: 0x00004a15a51f28ea
  R12: 0xffffff8010975d55, R13: 0xffffff8010c42580, R14: 0x0000000000000001, R15: 0xfffffd000004c720
  RFL: 0x0000000000010046, RIP: 0xffffff8010200a1c, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
  Fault CR2: 0xffffff805050600c, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 2, VF: 5

  Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
  0xfffffd000004c1d0 : 0xffffff801024f606 
  0xfffffd000004c220 : 0xffffff801037c654 
  0xfffffd000004c260 : 0xffffff801036e149 
  0xfffffd000004c2e0 : 0xffffff8010201120 
  0xfffffd000004c300 : 0xffffff801024f03c 
  0xfffffd000004c430 : 0xffffff801024edbc 
  0xfffffd000004c490 : 0xffffff801036e339 
  0xfffffd000004c610 : 0xffffff8010201120 
  0xfffffd000004c630 : 0xffffff8010200a1c 
  0xffffff9143c13b30 : 0xffffff8010378dde 
  0xffffff9143c13b80 : 0xffffff8010378a7b 
  0xffffff9143c13c60 : 0xffffff801036889f 
  0xffffff9143c13ca0 : 0xffffff801027e801 
  0xffffff9143c13cd0 : 0xffffff801022e046 
  0xffffff9143c13d30 : 0xffffff801022dc93 
  0xffffff9143c13da0 : 0xffffff801022f6d1 
  0xffffff9143c13e10 : 0xffffff8010231d0d 
  0xffffff9143c13e60 : 0xffffff8010244b7b 
  0xffffff9143c13ef0 : 0xffffff801035857d 
  0xffffff9143c13fa0 : 0xffffff8010201926 

  BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Safari

  Mac OS version:
  17D47

  Kernel version:
  Darwin Kernel Version 17.4.0: Sun Dec 17 09:19:54 PST 2017; root:xnu-4570.41.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
  Kernel UUID: 18D901F1-4A03-3FF1-AE34-C26B2732F13C
  Kernel slide:     0x000000000fe00000
  Kernel text base: 0xffffff8010000000
  __HIB  text base: 0xffffff800ff00000
  System model name: MacBookPro12,1 (Mac-E43C1C25D4880AD6)

  System uptime in nanoseconds: 81457567887808
  last loaded kext at 78500135352293: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f92671000, size 28672)
  last unloaded kext at 62308136600854: com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice  1.2 (addr 0xffffff7f92565000, size 28672)
  loaded kexts:
  com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
  com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.16.21
  com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.16.2
  com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
  com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
  com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
  com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.2f2
  com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.30
  com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
  com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
  com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
  com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
  com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
  com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
  com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphics  10.3.0
  com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   280.12
  com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
  com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.10.2
  com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.1
  com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    211
  com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC    1220.28.1a3
  com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetooth20703USBTransport  6.0.2f2
  com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
  com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   6.01.2
  com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
  com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.3
  com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphicsFramebuffer   10.3.0
  com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
  com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 439.30.4
  com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.41.3
  com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.30.1
  com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
  com.apple.BootCache 40
  com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
  com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329
  com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 127
  com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
  com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
  com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
  com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
  com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
  com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
  com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
  com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   183
  com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
  com.apple.security.quarantine   3
  com.apple.IOBufferCopyEngineTest    1
  com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
  com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
  com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
  com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.16.21
  com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
  com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 280.12
  com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    526
  com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.16.2
  com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
  com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   517.22
  com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
  com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
  com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
  com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 280.12
  com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 280.12
  com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
  com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
  com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.2f2
  com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.2f2
  com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.2f2
  com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
  com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
  com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
  com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
  com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
  com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.16.21
  com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    376.6
  com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    517.22
  com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   209.2.2
  com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
  com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
  com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
  com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.40.2
  com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.0.2
  com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.0.2
  com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
  com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    1204.13
  com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
  com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   203
  com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 127
  com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.2f2
  com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.2f2
  com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  1204.13
  com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    1201.8
  com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    52
  com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.5.6
  com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.6.3
  com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  52
  com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    3.0.60
  com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
  com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 3.0.60
  com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
  com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
  com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
  com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
  com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
  com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
  com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
  com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
  com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
  com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
  com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
  com.apple.iokit.IOBufferCopyEngineFamily    1
  com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.30.2
  com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
  com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
  com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
  com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.30.4
  com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
  com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140.30.1
  com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.30.2
  com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.30.2
  com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
  com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
  com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
  com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
  com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
  com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
  com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
  com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
  com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    650.5
  com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
  com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
  com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
  com.apple.driver.AppleSMCRTC    1.0
  com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
  com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
  com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
  com.apple.kec.pthread   1
  com.apple.kec.Libm  1
  com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

  EOF
  Model: MacBookPro12,1, BootROM MBP121.0171.B00, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.9 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.28f7
  Graphics: Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Built-In
  Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x4544464132333241324D412D4A442D460000
  Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x4544464132333241324D412D4A442D460000
  AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x133), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.37.5.1a3)
  Bluetooth: Version 6.0.2f2, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
  Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
  Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0512G, 500.28 GB
  USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
  USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
  Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
  ```

Comment: I started experiencing the same thing all of a sudden under 10.13.3 on an early 2015 MacBook within the last week; similarly no issues found by hardware diagnostics. Like you, no consistency to cause or process, and no listed kexts that aren't com.apple.

Answer (score 1):

I probably experience similar issues with my early 2015-MBP @16GB Ram. To me it appears possible, that my system never ran 100% stable, but I blamed a combination of USB-2xRJ45-Adaptor and VMWare Fusion - until the freezes of my system made it impossible to work. 
I ran the Apple-Diagnostic-Tool (d boot), stating the system is fine. However, memtest86 (usb Boot stick) eventually crashes at #13-Hammer-Test with cannot start CPU2. 
To me it appears to be an escalated hardware issue, probably existing since beginning

Would the two of you be so kind and report, how your issues “turned out” or what the final diagnosis on your systems was?

Thank you a lot.
Cheers from Berlin. [image]